# Best way to address several type of users in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php    
if($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'a' && $condition3 == 'a'){
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
    }

    if($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'a' && $condition3 == 'b'){
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
    }

    if($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'b' && $condition3 == 'a'){
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
    }

    if($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'b' && $condition3 == 'b'){
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
    }
?>
```

I have some 7 conditions and dozens of combinations. I want to know is this the right way to address each unique type of user or there can be some better approach?

HEREDOCS for every single combination is totally different from others.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

A switch with concatenated key may be the answer for you:

```
switch ($condition1.":".$condition2.":".$condition3){
    case "a:a:a":
        //echoing some HEREDOCS here
        break;
    case "a:a:b":
        //echoing some HEREDOCS here
        break;
    case "a:b:a":
        //echoing some HEREDOCS here
        break;
    case "a:b:b":
        //echoing some HEREDOCS here
        break;
}
```

Or alternatively you could create a message map

```
$messages = array(
          "a:a:a"=>"Docs a:a:a",
          "a:a:b"=>"Docs a:a:b",
          "a:b:a"=>"Docs a:b:a",
          "a:b:b"=>"Docs a:b:b",
);

echo $messages[$condition1.":".$condition2.":".$condition3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `switch` operator.

As far as your design is concerned, you might want to have each persons text stored in the database and pull it up with the user!

Answer (score 1):

I always like to design my code to avoid this kind of situation. Try to define a linear list of situations first, like:

```
<?php    

if($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'a' && $condition3 == 'a') $user_type = 1;
elseif($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'a' && $condition3 == 'b') $user_type = 2;
elseif($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'b' && $condition3 == 'a') $user_type = 3;
elseif($condition1 == 'a' && $condition2 == 'b' && $condition3 == 'b') $user_type = 4;
```

?>

Just don't forget to cover every possible combination, otherwise all ifs may fail, making `$user_type` undefined.

Later, when you want to print something, or take any action based on user type, just do a switch / case:

```
switch($user_type)
{
  case 1:
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
  break;
  case 2:
    //echoing some HEREDOCS here
  break;
}
```

The general idea is to handle the complicated thing only once, to avoid duplicating your complex logic all around your code.